# get complete url using nginx and lua with openresty

Tags: nginx, lua

If request URL is

```
test.com/gifts.
```

If i am using

```
 ngx.var.uri
```

output is

```
/gifts/
```

expected output is

```
test.com/gifts
```

Code :

```
 location /gifts {
                    try_files $uri @url_change;
                }


                location @url_change {
                default_type text/html;
                content_by_lua '

                        ngx.say(ngx.var.uri)
                         ';
                }
```

Comment: you can get it by, ngx.var.request_uri

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't really understand what you want, but if you want the actual full URL i think you can use this

```
$http_host$request_uri;
```

Comment: This is nowhere near a "complete URL" that would contain scheme, user if present, password if present, host, port if present, path, and query if present.

Comment: Thanks, your help works like a charm, `$request_uri` will get full uri event `.html`

Comment: `ngx.var.scheme.."://".. ngx.var.http_host.. ngx.var.request_uri.."?"..ngx.var.query_string`

Comment: @ahuigo I got "attempt to concatenate field 'query_string' (a nil value)" error

Answer (score 15):

If anyone is looking for the **original request uri**, it's here:

`ngx.var.request_uri`

While `ngx.var.uri` is the new uri after ngx rewrite phase.

Try it:

`ngx.say(ngx.var.request_uri)`

Answer (score 6):

```
ngx.say(ngx.var.host .. '/' .. ngx.var.uri)
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't what you need just the `$host` variable, i.e. `ngx.var.host`?

Comment: Can you please have a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120020/how-to-append-request-uri-from-nginx-in-jax-rs-rest-api/26130185#26130185)?

Comment: @abi1964's question has been moved or removed.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon: Sorry it was deleted. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the full url and avoid getting an error when query_string is **nil**:

```
local full_url = ngx.var.scheme.."://"..ngx.var.http_host..ngx.var.request_uri
if ngx.var.query_string ~= nil then
  full_url = full_url.."?"..ngx.var.query_string
end
ngx.say(full_url)
```